# What's the relevance of Tommy Franks and Geneva Convention to Robust Regression?

Tags: regression, references

I am reading [Modern Regression Techniques Using R](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Regression-Techniques-Using-Practical/dp/1847879020) (Wright and London, 2011).

At the end of the chapter on "Robust regression", in the summary of "Statistical concepts", there it says,

> "to Tommy Franks: to ridicule the Geneva Convention*"
>
> "* According to a quotation from the Lancet paper"

I can't figure what it tries to say or convey?

Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Maybe you could expand the quote "to Tommy Franks:"... to give some context?

Answer (score 2):

Using Google I found Tommy Franks derogatory quote about Douglas Feith that appears in Bob Woodward's book "Plan of Attack" and is related to the Geneva convention.  Unfrotunately I have not able to find a connection to robust regression yet. See http://www.nndb.com/people/100/000047956/.
As I research this more I think this was most likely a joke perhaps related to this:

> "In December 2001, Secretary of Defense Donald Rumsfeld and then Bush received Franks’s preliminary commander’s estimate, followed by
>   the first workable’, in Tenet’s words, Iraq war plan put to Bush on 1
>   February 2002 and successive plans through to Bush’s final approval on
>   6 September.[22] One of the variables from the outset was the degree
>   of international support and involvement. The assumptions about levels
>   of allied support ranged from ‘robust’ through ‘reduced’ to nil. If
>   the American military had their way, they would operate unilaterally,
>   but pressures come from the politicians to make room for allies."

I found this quote of Franks which is most likely connected to the Lancet article:

> "In the article below we were wrong to say that a household survey conducted by the World Health Organisation and the Iraqi health
>   ministry found that the rate of violent deaths had doubled in Iraq
>   after the invasion. The survey did not make this finding. Figures that
>   were unadjusted for under-reporting showed a doubling of the rate of
>   all deaths and a violence-related death rate about 11 times higher.
>   The article said the survey estimated that 151,000 civilians had been
>   killed since the invasion. That figure included combatants. The
>   article below should have also made clear that the Lancet and Opinion
>   Research Business surveys included combatants as well as civilians."

---

> " Lieutenant General Tommy Franks, who led the invasions of Iraq and
>   Afghanistan during his time as head of US Central Command, once
>   announced, "We don't do body counts." This blunt response to a
>   question about civilian casualties was an attempt to distance George
>   Bush's wars from the disaster of Vietnam. One of the rituals of that
>   earlier conflict was the daily announcement of how many Vietnamese
>   fighters US forces had killed. It was supposed to convince a sceptical
>   American public that victory was coming. But the 'body count' concept
>   sounded callous - and never more so than when it emerged that many of
>   the alleged guerrilla dead were in fact women, children and other
>   unarmed civilians."

Comment: Michael, we follow standard academic conventions here concerning the use and acknowledgment of other people's work.  They include (1) clearly attributing direct quotations and (2) avoiding posts that are almost entirely pulled from other sources. (Overuse of the latter is an invitation to downvoting, by the way.) I have reformatted this post to indicate the portions that appear to be quotations (and not your own words), and apologize if the result is imperfect.  It would be good if you could further improve this reply to follow those principles.

Comment: Will do as I find time.